# Hide table rows with expired content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I use a table to display scheduled content, and I want rows to disappear after their date has passed.

```
Row 1 has Table title
Row 2 has Date A
Row 3 has Scheduled content A1
Row 4 has Scheduled content A2
Row 5 has Date B
Row 6 has Scheduled content B1
Row 7 has Scheduled content B2
Row 5 has Date C
Row 6 has Scheduled content C1
Row 7 has Scheduled content C2
etc.
```

After Date A has passed, I want rows 2-4 to disappear/be hidden.

I do this website on a volunteer basis, and there is nobody else available to help.  I delete the expired rows on a daily basis, but I'm going on vacation and will be unplugged for two weeks.

I don't have any example code, I'm a rookie.  If you mean my html code, it's just a simple table.

***Sorry for not responding sooner, Jakub (https://stackoverflow.com/users/158014/jakub).  Spent 12+ hours in hospital ER with my daughter right after my last edit yesterday.  I will come back and fix the post to conform to Stackoverflow standards ASAP.***

Comment: This question doesn't fit the StackOverflow format, please check the http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: In what format is the date presented? What's the HTML structure of the table (with some representative data)? While we're more than happy to help (yay, points!) we're not going to take blind guesses at what you might be doing: help us to help you, that way everybody wins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery library to hide certain parts of the website on certain dates. It should help on this case while you are off.

First load jQuery, adding to the head section of your site:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then your table in the body section:

Then, near the end of the body tag, you create a rule for hiding content based on a date:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var now = new Date();
var futuretime1 = new Date("April 10, 2013");
if(now > futuretime1)
 {
 $("#div").hide();
 }
</script>
```

This will hide #div when date passes "futuretime1". You can also use jQuery selectors for selecting the appropriate table row.

Hope this helps.